# Substring, if the string is not long enough replace chars with spaces

Tags: c#, substring

I'm trying to compare first 3 chars of a string, i'm trying to use substring then compare.

The strings are read from an input file, and the string may not be 3 chars long. if an string is not 3 chars long i want the substring method to replace the empty chars with spaces.

How would i go about doing that.

Current code throws an exeption when the string is not long enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [String.PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a.aspx)

```
myString.PadRight(3, ' ');
// do SubString here..
```

You could also create a [`.Left` extension method](http://wordaligned.org/articles/rewriting-stringleft) that doesn't throw an exception when the string isn't big enough:

```
public static string Left(this string s, int len)
{
    if (len == 0 || s.Length == 0)
        return "";
    else if (s.Length <= len)
        return s;
    else
        return s.Substring(0, len);
}
```

Usage:

```
myString.Left(3);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use one of the [String.PadRight() methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az8d6582.aspx) before calling Substring():

```
string subString = myString.PadRight(3).Substring(0,3);
```

If you use the overload with one parameter like I did above, it will insert spaces.

```
string subString1 = string1.PadRight(3).Substring(0,3);
string subString2 = string2.PadRight(3).Substring(0,3);
if (String.Compare(subString1, subString2) == 0)
{
    // if equal
}
else
{
    // not equal
}
```

I used separate variables because it's a bit more readable, but you could in-line them in the if statement if you wanted to.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this dirty hack:

```
var res = (myStr+"    ").Substring(...);
```

Comment: @mellamokb I use it a lot, but I think I'll switch to `PadRight` (I just upvoted your answer).